# All we can できるだけは できるのは

Tags: grammar

Does this Japanese sentence make sense?

その問題を解くために、私たちができるだけはできるのは、ほとんどありません。

I would like to say:

*There is not much we can do about solving this problem.*

The more literal translation would be:

*In order to solve this problem, all we can do is almost nothing.*

For the grammatical construction "できるだけはできるのは", please refer to this [link](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%AF-dake-wa/).

Answer (score 3):

私たちができるだけはできるのは is unnatural. I say it like その問題を解くために、私たちができることは、ほとんどありません. "all we can" is literally translated as 私達ができるすべてのこと". However you may omit すべての and we usually omit it.

I think you should use this phrase できるだけ～する as the translation of "to do all that one can". For example, 覚えられるだけ覚えた(I've remembered everything I ciould).